# Problem with firebase_in_app_messaging dependency. Getting error : "Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRInAppMessaging' "

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies, firebase-in-app-messaging

I've installed `firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.1.2` Flutter lib from pub.dev. After that, I couldn't run the app because iOS can't see `FIRInAppMessaging`. Checked in Xcode Pods/Targets there is no `FirebaseInAppMessaging` pod installed. Does anybody else had this problem and knows how to fix it?

I've tried fixing it with adding `pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging'` into the Podfile and running `pod install` and it works but I am searching for a better solution because Podfile is autogenerated file in Flutter.

Comment: This is probably the only solution to this problem that is also on github.